# How do I scrape the character literal in a wikitable using nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, wikipedia

I am writing a method in ruby that scrapes each letter of a wikitable using nokogiri. This method is in my Scraper class. I just want the character in the 'Letter' row.

Here is my code so far:

```
def self.scrape_tables
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet"
        doc = HTTParty.get(url)
        parsed_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)

        # capture each row
        rows = parsed_doc.css('table.wikitable tr')
        letters = rows.css('td a')
        
        # add each letter to letters_array
        letters_array = []
        letters.map do |letter|
            letter_name = letter.name
            letters_array.push(letter)
        end
        binding.pry
    end
```

It appears I am grabbing the right tags when I type the following in binding.pry

```
puts letters
```

I can see all of the characters I want in an <a href ... > tag. However, it's not the literal character.

Once I can figure out how to select the character, then I will be able to populate letters_array appropriately.

Is there something I am missing in the .css selector method? Thanks!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small mistake in the code, `letter` it pushed instead of `letter_name`.

This should work:

```
def self.scrape_tables
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet"
    doc = HTTParty.get(url)
    parsed_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)

    # capture each row
    rows = parsed_doc.css('table.wikitable tr')
    letters = rows.css('td a')
    
    # add each letter to letters_array
    letters_array = []
    letters.map do |letter|
        letter_name = letter.name
        letters_array.push(letter_name)
    end
end
```

If you want to get the actual text value inside the a tag, you need to do `letter_name = letter.text`

**Update to get all letters from the first column:**

To get all only values from the first column one need to use `first-child`, and you need to force that the td element has a tag, otherwise it
includes a few of the rows with rowspan that contains citations.

```
parsed_doc.css('table.wikitable tr td:first-child > a').map(&:text)
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```